# How to configure EF 5.0 code first to create separate table with each enum type

Tags: entity-framework

I've used the following enum in my code first models

```
public enum Role
    {
        Reviewer = 1,
        Requester = 2,
        Approver = 3
    }
```

It is used in the User entity like below

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

        public Role Role { get; set; }


    }
```

EF creates a single table Users in the database and role is stored there as int. 
What I need here is another table named "Roles" with Id and Desc. Id is the value of the enum and Desc is its name. And this table will be automatically populated on model creation.

Does EF has some feature for it? Or do I have to create another entity for Role and populate that manually?

Comment: You cannot create a table from an enum, you need to create another entity.

Comment: Would be a nice feature, because it is a way to ensure that values in the database match the ones in the enum. But @RuiJarimba is right, it is [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx) (point 4 at the end). Can't change the facts.